# How to display a view of products that are selectable

Tags: views, 7, entities

I am working on a site that will capture site details by the sales reps. They will also use the site to order products for the customer and at the same time enter the installation criteria of the product by uploading photos and filling out text boxes.

The site will need to display all the products (50) in a table like views would on the page at once. The products will need to have a check box to select each product and a quantity to be entered. The products entered will need to be saved to the specific site that the sales rep has sold to.

In the screen shot I am using panels to layout the form. I have highlighted in red the image I am currently displaying with html in panels.

I have tried a few modules like Entity Reference / Views and Commerce but cannot find the best way to tackle this. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks.
Drupal 7.31

[Screen Shot http://sitetrack.com.au/images/Screen_capture_1.PNG](http://sitetrack.com.au/images/Screen_capture_1.PNG)

Answer (score 0):

Save a lot of head-scratching (not all though;) and use Drupal Commerce Custom Product:

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product

It's not that you can't do this with 'normal' Drupal, it's just that Commerce Custom Product is set up to do precisely what you want... so might as well use it!

HTH

Steve